# Does there exist a metric $d$ on $\Bbb{R}$ such that $\overline{(0,1)}=[0,1]\cup \{2\}$ w.r.to. $d$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose there is such $d$. Then let $A=(0,1)$ and define $f(x)=d(x,A)$. This map is lipschitz with constant $1$.

We know that $d(x,A)=0\iff x\in\overline{A}$. Then as per given $\overline{A}$, $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0\text{ if }x\in [0,1]\cup \{2\}\\
>0\text{ if otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

This is not giving any contradiction.

Can anyone give a hint how to approach the problem? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: if there is no contradiction, then maybe there is an example that you should be looking for instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bijection and $d_E$ be the usual euclidean metric. Then $d(x,y)=d_E(f(x),f(y))$ is also a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ (check this). Now, we can consider a bijection $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g((0,1))=(0,1/2)\cup (1/2,1)$ and $g(0)=0, g(1)=1$ and $g(2)=1/2$. This metric will do what you want (is this clear?).

**Added:** As WimC pointed out in the comment below, we could also take $g$ to just swap $2$ and $1/2$, which is much easier than what I wrote above.

Comment: Or let $g$ just swap $\tfrac12$ and $2$.

Comment: @WimC I realized that your elegant solution was not included in what I wrote above. Thanks for improving the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Of course there is such a metric $d$.  Equivalent question: Is there a metric space, and a subset $A$ of cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$, such that $\overline{A} \setminus A$ has exactly $3$ points.  Easy.

Comment: I am not getting it, can you give a hint?

Comment: @MathBS do you want to know why it is equivalent or why you can find such a metric space?